# Python Caesar Cipher

Tags: python

I need to create a code for Caesar Cipher. I need to use a for loop to examine every character of text, find shifted character using ALPHABET, key, and String functions, and add this to the end of "encipheredTextSoFar". Need help, not finished but I'm stuck.

EDIT:

I finally got it and this is my final code:

```
def circularShift(text, key):
    text = text.upper()
    cipher = ""
    for letter in text:
        shifted = ord(letter) + key
        if shifted < 65:
            shifted += 26
        if shifted > 90:
            shifted -= 26
        cipher += chr(shifted)
    return cipher

print (circularShift("MOLLOY", 3))
print (circularShift("PROORB", -3))
```

Comment: Do you have a specific question? This is a Q&A site... not a homework help/tutorial/cheat site. A quick search yields many similar questions and answers already on Stack Overflow. Always remember to search before asking and please read the help: http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic

Comment: I just need some help, i'm not trying to cheat, i'm very new to programming so i'm just very confused on everything. I've been trying to work on this code by myself until i got stuck and i can't think of anything else to do

Comment: find your question, and then perhaps, you will find your answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

##### Python source code:

```
# setting status default value to 'y'
status = 'y'

# started a while loop until status will change from 'y' to 'n'
while status == 'y':
    # requesting which word to cipher.
    word = str(raw_input("Word: "))
    # how many position to shift each letter
    shift = int(input("Shift: "))
    # added new line to have pretty output
    print

    # declaring cipher variable to be of type list
    cipher = list()
    # iterating trough each character in word
    for item in word:
        # translanting each characher in word to new character
        # and appending it to cipher list
        cipher.append(chr(ord(item)+shift))

    # printing word
    print word
    # printing ciphered word
    print ''.join(cipher)

    print
    # do We need to cipher another word? yes or no?
    status = raw_input("Repeat? [y|n]: ")
    print
```

##### Output:

```
>>> 
Word: HelLo
Shift: 1

HelLo
IfmMp

Repeat? [y|n]: y

Word: AbCdEF
Shift: 2

AbCdEF
CdEfGH

Repeat? [y|n]: y

Word: abc
Shift: -1

abc
`ab

Repeat? [y|n]: y

Word: 456GHh
Shift: -2

456GHh
234EFf

Repeat? [y|n]: n

>>>
```

Answer (score 1):

simple Implementation using: `string.maketrans`

```
 import string
 upper_case = string.uppercase
 trans = lambda x,n:string.maketrans(x,x[n:]+x[:n])
 def ceaser(text,n):
    print text.upper().translate(trans(upper_case,n))
 ceaser("MOLLOY",3)
 ceaser("HELLO",6)
```

output:

```
PROORB
KHOOR
```

Answer (score 0):

```
alphabet = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'i', 'j', 'k', 'l', 'm', 'n', 'o', 'p', 'q', 'r', 's', 't', 'u', 'v', 'w', 'x', 'y', 'z']

def encrypt(texted, shifted):
    crypted_message = ''
    for letter in texted:
        if letter in alphabet:
            index_in_alphabet = alphabet.index(letter)
            crypted_message += alphabet[(index_in_alphabet + shifted) % 26]
        else:
            crypted_message += letter
    print(f"message crypté : {crypted_message}")

def decrypt(texted, shifted):
    decrypted_message = ''
    for letter in texted:
        if letter in alphabet:
            index_in_alphabet = alphabet.index(letter)
            decrypted_message += alphabet[(index_in_alphabet - shifted) % 26]
        else:
            decrypted_message += letter
    print(f"message decrypté : {decrypted_message}")

request = 'yes'
while request == 'yes':
    direction = input("Type 'encode' to encrypt, type 'decode' to decrypt : \n")
    while direction != "encode" and direction != "decode":
        print("Entrez soit 'encode' ou 'decode'")
        direction = input("Type 'encode' to encrypt, type 'decode' to decrypt : \n")

    text = input("Type your message:\n").lower()
    shift = int(input("Type the shift number:\n"))
    while shift > 26:
        print("Enterez un chiffre entre 0 et 25")
        shift = int(input("Type the shift number:\n"))

    if direction == 'encode':
        encrypt(texted=text, shifted=shift)
    else:
        decrypt(texted=text, shifted=shift)
    request = input("Type 'yes' if u want go agin . 'no' if else :\n")
```

Comment: You can get more [formatting help here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting). For now check my edit to understand how to format code